# Setting focus from viewmodel does not work properly

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, viewmodel

I'm trying to setting the focus for a certain UIElement dependency object from viewmodel and to do that I have written an Attached Dependency Property as below:

```
    #region IsFocusedProperty
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsFocused", typeof(bool), typeof(AttachedProperties),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,
            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsFocusedChanged)));

    private static void OnIsFocusedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = d as UIElement;

        var oldValue = (bool)e.OldValue;
        var newValue = (bool)e.NewValue;

        if (oldValue != newValue && !obj.IsFocused)
        {
            obj.Focus();
        }
    }

    public static void SetIsFoused(UIElement element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsFocused(UIElement element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
    }
    #endregion
```

I should say it works and sends the focus to the specified element unless when I move the mouse cursor over each element in the view (including the specified element on which the focus is) no mouse event fires. I'm saying this because I've written triggers for IsMouseOverProperty of the elements but nothings happen when the focus is sent to the specified element in that way.

I should also say that the triggers works fine again when I click anywhere on the view. I really don't know what the problem is? please share your ideas. any idea would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

**Edit**:
I've figured it out that the element receives the keyboard focus but apparently not the logical focus because when I move the cursor to the previous element, it still fires MouseMove event.

I'm still not sure what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Update to:

```
if (oldValue != newValue && !obj.IsFocused)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input,
        new Action(delegate() 
        { 
            obj.Focus();        
            Keyboard.Focus(obj); 
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank @d.moncada but it's still not working properly.